# $C_v$ for polytropic process having equation $PV^{x}=k$

Tags: thermodynamics

Polytropic process has an equation $PV^{x}=k$.

But from this how can we conclude $C_v=\dfrac{R}{x-1}$ or $C_p=\dfrac{xR}{x-1} $ ?

I could'nt find any proof on the net.

Comment: Your expressions are weird. Are you sure about them? Probably you were supposed to strip of the $\Delta T$'s? Or do you mean that this is the amount of heat transferred during the process, in which you shouldn't be using the symbols for specific heat? We need some clarification. Can you explain what these equations are supposed to represent?

Comment: Then, do you really mean polytropic process here? I suspect that you mean the *specific* case of an adiabatic, quasi-equilibrium process. In that case, set up a thermodynamic cycle composed of an adiabatic expansion followed by an isothermal compression back to the original volume, then followed by an isovolumetric process back to the original state. Use the First Law to relate the heat flows and work done for the entire process, and you will be able to solve the specific heat at constant volume. Similar for $C_p$. This really should be in any thermo textbook (maybe as an exercise).

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108933/formula-for-molar-specific-heat-capacity-in-polytropic-process       might be of interest to you

Comment: Yes there's a problem because your expressions are *only* true if the process is an adiabatic process (which is a special case of a polytropic process). The linked Q&A above has an explanation as to why.

Comment: The question already has an answer on Physics SE, as indicated by CountTo10.

Comment: $\gamma$ is $x$. And you need to *derive* that $C_v$ is equal to $R/(\gamma-1)$ by doing what I suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

This is my attempt at a more general approach /alternative to what is presented on  [Polytropic Process Molar Heat Capacity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108933/formula-for-molar-specific-heat-capacity-in-polytropic-process)

Please note **attempt** rather than answer, so I am trying to put it all together, but this attempt is based on notes I  took only last week, but hopefully it will still be useful in some way.

I have used $x $ to avoid (hopefully), confusion with the $n$ usually used as the polytropic power, and to correspond with your notation.

The specific heat for a polytropic process is given by $$C_n = C_v\frac   {\gamma − n} {1 − n}$$  where $$\gamma = \frac {C_p} {C_v} $$

$C_n$  corresponds to the value of $n$. If $n = 0$ (an isobaric process) we have 
$$C_0 = C_v\frac {\gamma} {1} = C_v \frac {C_p }{C_v} = C_p $$

The source of these equations above  is [Wikipedia 
Polytropic Processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytropic_process)

Using: $$\delta Q = n C_x d T$$
 and

$$dU = n C_v dT $$

Starting with: 
$$dU = dQ + \delta W $$

Now, just concentrating on Work, leaving anything else for you to slog through and subsitute the relevant expressions, sorry:)

$$W = − \frac  {P_i V_i} {( x − 1 )} \left[\left (\frac {V_i} {V_f }\right)^{ x − 1} − 1 \right] $$

$$=  − \frac {x R T_i} {( x − 1 )} \left[\left (\frac {V_i} {V_f }\right )^{ x − 1} − 1 \right]$$

Incorporating the ideal gas law into the polytropic equation gives

$$\left (\frac { V_i }{V_f }\right) ^{x − 1} = \frac {T_f} {T_i} $$

Putting all this together results in :$$ W = − \frac {x R} {( x − 1 )} ( T_f − T_i ) $$

Substituting this into the first law gives: 
$$n C_x \Delta T = x C_p \Delta T −\frac  { x  R\Delta T}{(x − 1)} $$

Finding a common denominator for the right hand side:

$$C_p = \frac  { x  R}{(x − 1)}$$