# How can $dQ=nC_mdT$ be used in various thermodynamic proofs?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

I have seen the equation $dQ=nC_mdT$ for ideal gases often used in certain proofs in thermodynamics(such as $C_m$ for polytopric process). However, I feel this expression is wrong as a general statement.

For example, if we have an isothermal process then using the above expression we would get $dQ=0$.  However, heat transfer is very common in isothermal processes.

Am I correct? If yes, then how can this expression be used in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108933/formula-for-molar-specific-heat-capacity-in-polytropic-process) proof?

Answer (score 0):

The equation $\delta Q=nC_X\,dT$ can be applied to any material or system but always comes with an implicit assumption:

"I am heating (or cooling) the system via heating $\delta Q^{(\star )}$ under condition $X$ (e.g., constant pressure $P$ or constant volume $V$) **and doing nothing else**."

<sub>$(\star )$ I use $\delta$ because $Q$ isn't a state function we can take the derivative of.</sub>

That is, I'm not doing work on or extracting work from the system, and I'm not adding or removing mass.

In fact, since heating transfers entropy $S$ (with $\delta Q_\text{rev}=T\,dS$), this provides a useful way to define the molar heat capacity under condition $X$ as $$C_X=\frac{T}{n}\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_X.$$

As you've noticed, an isothermal state can be maintained by heating an ideal  gas while letting it expand, for example. The equation $\delta Q=nC_X\,dT$ is not valid in this scenario.

However, a useful alternative equation is $dU=nC_V\,dT$ (where $C_V$ is the constant-volume molar heat capacity), which always applies to an ideal gas under all conditions and processes. This equation tells us that we can maintain a constant temperature in an ideal gas if the heat input (output) exactly equals the work output (input).

(The presence of the term "constant-volume" in that equation often confuses new thermodynamics practitioners. It's just part of the name of the constant of proportionality; it doesn't place any constraints on any particular process. A more general equation for all systems is $dU=C_V\,dT+(\alpha TK-P)\,dV$, where $\alpha$ is the **constant-pressure** thermal expansion coefficient and $K$ is the **constant-temperature** stiffness; it just so happens that $\alpha=1/T$ and $K=P$ for the ideal gas, so the second term vanishes, and the only material property left is one with "**constant-volume**" in its name. See [here](http://john.maloney.org/cruelest_equation.htm) for a much longer discussion of this point.)

Answer (score 0):

In my judgment, you are correct.  Since C is supposed to represent a physical property of the material, it should really only be defined in terms of the equilibrium thermodynamic functions for the materiaL;$$nC_v=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_v$$$$nC_P=\left(\frac{\partial H}{\partial T}\right)_P$$Since Q is not an equilibrium thermodynamic function, but rather a path-dependent parameter, it should, strictly speaking, not be used to define C. Still, some teachers, for fun, like to see what C would come out to be if specified in terms of Q for, say, a polytropic path.